# Winsorize dataframe

Tags: r, transformation

I want to perform winsorization in a dataframe like this:

```
event_date  beta_before     beta_after
2000-05-05  1.2911707054    1.3215648954
1999-03-30  0.5089734305    0.4269575657
2000-05-05  0.5414700258    0.5326762272
2000-02-09  1.5491034852    1.2839988507
1999-03-30  1.9380674599    1.6169735009
1999-03-30  1.3109909155    1.4468207148
2000-05-05  1.2576420753    1.3659492507
1999-03-30  1.4393018341    0.7417777965
2000-05-05  0.2624037804    0.3860641307
2000-05-05  0.5532216441    0.2618245169
2000-02-08  2.6642931822    2.3815576738
2000-02-09  2.3007578964    2.2626960407
2001-08-14  3.2681270302    2.1611010935
2000-02-08  2.2509121123    2.9481325199
2000-09-20  0.6624503316    0.947935581
2006-09-26  0.6431111805    0.8745333151
```

By winsorization I mean to find the max and min for beta_before for example. That value should be replaced by the second highest or second lowest value in the same column, without loosing the rest of the details in the observation. For example. In this case, in beta_before the max value is 3.2681270302 and should be replaced by 3.2681270302. The same process will be followed for the min and then for the beta_after variable. Therefore, only 2 values per column will be changes, the highest and the minimum, the rest will remain the same.

Any advice? I tried different approaches in plyr, but I ended up replacing the whole observation, which I don’t want to do. I would like to create 2 new variables, for example beta_before_winsorized and beta _after_winsorized

Comment: This isn't quite making sense. Your before and after max value are the same. I'm also perplexed by the use of plyr. Are you doing some type of grouping by date? Plyr is a tool for splitting, applying and combining. I can't tell what your split is here.

Comment: @JD Long. This is just a subset of the actual dataframe. The actual dataframe includes another column with different values. Different "events" are grouped by a combination of two variables, hence, `plyr` is useful in my case. I did a mistake in my description, the before and after values are not the same. Thank you for your comment, and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that does the winsorzation you describe:

```
winsorize <- function(x) {
    Min <- which.min(x)
    Max <- which.max(x)
    ord <- order(x)
    x[Min] <- x[ord][2]
    x[Max] <- x[ord][length(x)-1]
    x
}
```

If you data are in a data frame `dat`, then we can windsoroize the data using your procedure via:

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[, -1] <- sapply(dat[,-1], winsorize)
```

which results in:

```
R> dat2
   event_date beta_before beta_after
1  2000-05-05   1.2911707  1.3215649
2  1999-03-30   0.5089734  0.4269576
3  2000-05-05   0.5414700  0.5326762
4  2000-02-09   1.5491035  1.2839989
5  1999-03-30   1.9380675  1.6169735
6  1999-03-30   1.3109909  1.4468207
7  2000-05-05   1.2576421  1.3659493
8  1999-03-30   1.4393018  0.7417778
9  2000-05-05   0.5089734  0.3860641
10 2000-05-05   0.5532216  0.3860641
11 2000-02-08   2.6642932  2.3815577
12 2000-02-09   2.3007579  2.2626960
13 2001-08-14   2.6642932  2.1611011
14 2000-02-08   2.2509121  2.3815577
15 2000-09-20   0.6624503  0.9479356
16 2006-09-26   0.6431112  0.8745333
```

I'm not sure where you got the value you suggest should replace the max in `beta_before` as the second highest is `2.6642932` in the snippet of data provided and that is what my function has used to replace with the maximum value with.

Note the function will only work if there is one minimum and maximum values respectively in each column owing to the way `which.min()` and `which.max()` are documented to work. If you have multiple entries taking the same max or min value then we would need something different:

```
winsorize2 <- function(x) {
    Min <- which(x == min(x))
    Max <- which(x == max(x))
    ord <- order(x)
    x[Min] <- x[ord][length(Min)+1]
    x[Max] <- x[ord][length(x)-length(Max)]
    x
}
```

should do it (latter is not tested).

Comment: Works exactly as needed. Great! It is obvious now that I know the answer!

Answer (score 8):

I thought winsorizing usually finds the value x% (typically 10%, 15%, or 20%) from the bottom of the ordered list, and replaces all the values below it with that value. Same with the top. Here you're just choosing the top and bottom value, but winsorizing usually involves specifying a percentage of values at the top and bottom to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, "winsorization" is the act of replacing the most extreme data points with an acceptable percentile (as mentioned in some of the other answers).  One fairly standard R function to do this is `winsor` from the `psych` package.  Try:

```
dat$beta_before = psych::winsor(dat$beta_before, trim = 0.0625)
dat$beta_after  = psych::winsor(dat$beta_after , trim = 0.0625)
```

I chose `trim =` to be 0.0625 (the 6.25th percentile and 93.75th percentile) because you only have 16 data points and you want to "rein in" the top and bottom ones:  1/16 = 0.0625

Note that this might make the extreme data equal to a percentile number which may or may not exist in your data set:  the theoretical n-th percentile of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `statar` package works very well for this. Copying the relevant snippet from the readme file:

```
# winsorize (default based on 5 x interquartile range)
v <- c(1:4, 99)
winsorize(v)
winsorize(v, replace = NA)
winsorize(v, probs = c(0.01, 0.99))
winsorize(v, cutpoints = c(1, 50))
```

https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar

Answer (score 0):

follow up from my previous point about actually replacing the to-be-trimmed values with value at trim position:

```
winsorized.sample<-function (x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
{
  if (!is.numeric(x) && !is.complex(x) && !is.logical(x)) {
    warning("argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA")
    return(NA_real_)
  }
  if (na.rm) 
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  if (!is.numeric(trim) || length(trim) != 1L) 
    stop("'trim' must be numeric of length one")
  n <- length(x)
  if (trim > 0 && n) {
    if (is.complex(x)) 
      stop("trimmed sample is not defined for complex data")
    if (any(is.na(x))) 
      return(NA_real_)
    if (trim >= 0.5) { 
      warning("trim >= 0.5 is odd...trying it anyway")
    }
    lo <- floor(n * trim) + 1
    hi <- n + 1 - lo
    #this line would work for just trimming 
    #  x <- sort.int(x, partial = unique(c(lo, hi)))[lo:hi]
    #instead, we're going to replace what would be trimmed
    #with value at trim position using the next 7 lines
    idx<-seq(1,n)
    myframe<-data.frame(idx,x)
    myframe<-myframe[ order(x,idx),]
    myframe$x[1:lo]<-x[lo]
    myframe$x[hi:n]<-x[hi]
    myframe<-myframe[ order(idx,x),]
    x<-myframe$x
  }
  x
}
#test it
mydist<-c(1,20,1,5,2,40,5,2,6,1,5)
mydist2<-winsorized.sample(mydist, trim=.2)
mydist
mydist2
descStat(mydist)
descStat(mydist2)
```